# fullscreen transition in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen, transition

I want to make a full-screen application with javaFX .. i used `stage.setFullScreen(true);` every time i change the scene like this

```
@Override
    public void start( Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Language.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);


        stage.show();
    }
```

the problem is while transition the full screen appears to be turned off then back on instantly and the "press esc ... " sign appears every single scene

is there a solution for this ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of full screen was solved by adding

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

to the stage and removing `setFullScreen(true);` from every scene except the main one !

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text that is displayed when entering full-screen with the [`Stage.setFullScreenExitHint(String value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreenExitHint-java.lang.String-) method.

Quoting from the javadoc:

> A value of `null` will result in the default per-locale message being displayed. If set to the empty string, then no message will be displayed.

Set an empty `String` to disable it:

```
stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
```

Comment: thanks :)   .. but is there any solution to the transition problem ?

Comment: i managed to solve it :) and posted the answer .. thx for your help :)